# VBA: Inserting Row within IF/Then Statement within For Loop

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to insert two rows and copy & paste the top row (header) every time a value changes within a column (This is a smaller task within a much larger macro in which I'm formatting data and pasting that data into outlook emails). For some reason, it appears my "if" statement is not being satisfied so none of the "then" code is being executed (i.e. no rows are being inserted), although the data is showing clear differences in values between "j+1" and "j+2" so rows should be inserted in between them. Per the below, do you see any reason as to why my if statement is flawed?

```
Function RangetoHtml(rng As Range)

Dim fso As Object
Dim ts As Object
Dim TempFile As String
Dim TempWB As Workbook
Dim TopR As Double
Dim j As Long
Dim LastR As Double

TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"


rng.Copy
Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        Range("B1").Select

        For j = 1 To 100
            If Cells(j + 1, 1).Value <> Cells(j + 2, 1).Value And Cells(j + 2, 1) <> 0 Then
            Rows(j + 2).Resize(2).EntireRow.Insert
            Rows("1").Copy
            Rows(j + 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            Rows(j + 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues              
            j = j + 2
            End If
        Next
```

I've added this below code for a dummy sheet I made to test my code and it's doing exactly what I want. I don't really see a difference between my code above and the code below, which doesn't seem to make sense at all:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("E1").Select
    For j = 1 To 100
        If Cells(j + 1, 1).Value <> Cells(j + 2, 1).Value And Cells(j + 2, 1) <> 0 Then
        Rows(j + 2).Resize(2).EntireRow.Insert
        Rows("1").Copy
        Rows(j + 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        Rows(j + 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        j = j + 2
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: It's difficult to provide an answer without seeing the data. Firstly, why declare `TopR` and `LastR` as type **Double**? These should be type **Long**. But for the data issues, place this line right above your `If...Then` statement and see what you are looking at in the debugger is what you expect that data to be: `Debug.Print "Value1=[" & Cells(j + 1, 1) & "] <> Value2=[" & Cells(j + 2, 1) & "]... Value3=[" & Cells(j + 2, 1) & "] <> 0"`

Comment: Also, you should add `Option Explicit` to the top of the module, you never declared your `j` variable, which should also be of type **Long**.

Comment: Your `If` statement is working. You don't need to declare `TopR`; since you select `B1` and then assign `TopR` to B1's row number, you are performing a run-a-round to declare `1`, so `For J = 1 To 100` would be easier to understand. I don't see where you are using `LastR`. When inserting rows you need to loop from the bottom to the top, or you will just keep inserting blank rows after the first time your `If` statement is `True`.

Comment: I don't believe I have to loop from the bottom as I'm re-designating j as j +2 at the end of the if statement to account for the two inserted rows. I have updated my code to have j = long and For j = 1 To 100. However, this hasn't seemed to resolve the issue, as no rows are being inserted when a new value is hit in column B, which is why I think my if statement is just incorrect.